# Nativescript error context is not fully stringified

Tags: nativescript

It makes development really hard when you can't see stacktrace and the context of the error. Is there any way to make nativescript errors more transparent? How I can manage to stringify the error context?

```
JS: ERROR TypeError: format.replace is not a function
JS: ERROR CONTEXT [object Object]
```

It is really hard to search for that null variable. A needle in the haystack...

Comment: i think no 100% sure but in your context "format" isn't a string and using replace need "format" as type string to be sure test by using alert(typeof format); if string is getting...etc Regards.

Comment: @headmax Thank you sir, just solved my issue by debugging Angular core modules and provided a workaround solution for people.

Comment: welcome, good luck for the next, regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround solution but still we should spend time to view the error context. 
If you are using Angular with Nativescript probably your error is being thrown from core.umd.js (@Angular). Without Nativescript every field of the error is visible. I found two solutions that still take time:

- **Method 1:** You can easily debug your error by placing a breakpoint to `callWithDebugContext` function.
- **Method 2:** You can catch any `throw` on any level using `try...catch`, you may wrap your method and stringify your err.context.

I am not considering top most level `try...catch` as a solution.

But these are still not the best way. Nativescript team should fix this console logging issue.

Comment: "Nativescript team should fix this console logging issue" https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/new . Also, the project is open source, and we accept all kinds of help. Become a contributor today!

Comment: @pkanev I will contribute asap with this feature, thank you.